# How to load two different models of tensorflow

Tags: tensorflow

I wonder load two different models of tensorflow. For example, one is for detection, and the other is for classification, the two model need to load in one program. The two models are both using

```
saver = tf.train.Saver()
saver.restore(isess, ckpt_filename)
```

to load. But the error occurs.Is there anybody successfully finishing this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can create different graph for the different models. Because when you restore the model from the checkpoint, the model will be stored in the default graph, that's why when you restore different model will cause error.